# Solvability of the groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $M$, $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G/M$ and $G/N$ are solvable groups. How can I prove that $G/(M\cap N)$ and $G/\langle M,N\rangle$ are solvable either?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Observe that with $M,N$ normal we deduce $\langle M,N\rangle=MN$. What do you know about $MN/M$? Anything that might come in handy here?

Comment: I changed ${}<M,N>{}$ to $\langle M,N\rangle$.  There are lists and tables of LaTeX symbols on the web.  With Google you can find these things.

Comment: More: What do you know about quotients and subgroups of solvable groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$MN/M\cong N/\left(M\cap N\right)$$

$$G/ N\cong\left(G/\left(M\cap N\right)\right)/\left(N/\left(M\cap N\right)\right)$$

$$G/MN\cong\left(G/N\right)/\left(MN/N\right)$$

Comment: Using all information written above and the theorem, that $G$ is solvable iff $G/H$ and $H$ are, for $H$-normal subgroup of $G$ it's enough to check that $N/(M\cap N)$ is the normal, solvable subgroup of $G/(M\cap N)$ and $MN/N$ is the normal, solvable subgroup of $G/N$.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes indeed, @DeltaDelta